# Select where first portion of input exist in column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, substring, web-crawler

I'm making a crawler for indexing some content, but need to block certain subdirectories from being indexed.
Those subdirectories are in table 'blocked', which only has columns 'id' and 'url'.
Any URL's that starts with the values in column 'url' should not be indexed.

One such directory that shouldn't be indexed could be:
    http://example.com/blocked/

Then I got this URL, and I want to check if that should be indexed:
http://example.com/blocked/some-content/123.html
(... it should not be indexed)

This query is obviously not what I want for this scenario:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM blocked WHERE url LIKE 'http://example.com/blocked/some-content/123.html%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do LIKE on the URL column like below

```
  SELECT count(id) 
  FROM blocked 
  WHERE @input  LIKE  
  CONCAT(URL, '%');
```